# Get request query string witout var

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a simple site (w/PHP). trying the get query string ex: http://phpmvc.loc/?url=hello would give me "hello", but with http://phpmvc.loc/hello would just say "Not Found". how do i get query string ("hello") without the var /?url=some-query-string.

Below is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /phpmvc.loc/public

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Also running my setup on Vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: replacing RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] with your RewriteRule ^url/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 -- not working. thanks for reply